# How can I open my application when a user try to open another application first? We want to trigger an event when a person opens another app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, security

The idea is to protect all the applications from your device. We want to have our application open first and check if the user is who he says he is. For example, if I'm trying to enter WhatsApp, I want my app to pop up and first ask me for my fingerprint and if those matches let me enter WhatsApp, otherwise don't let me and prompt me my fingerprint again until I got it right.

open WhatsApp ----> my app pops up and ask me for my fingerprint -----> if that's ok ----> continue to the next factor of authentication ---> if that is okay ---> enter WhatsApp

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this unless you're going to modify the Android OS to do so.  This is why devices have passwords and biotmetric screen locks-  you want to lock them out from even being able to open an app.  That's the solution to your problem, not doing it at the app level.  Which even if possible would be freaking annoying.

Comment: Maybe the question was too general. What we are trying to do is getting another factor of authentication because once your fingerprint is hacked you can not change it. So we want to mix fingerprint with another method. For example, using a 4 digit password.

Comment: You still won't be able to run another app before running an individual app without changing the Android OS.  Now if you want to do it at the lock screen-  it used to be possible to swap lock screens, back in the Android 2.3 days.  It's been removed for a long time.  So again you'd need to customize the OS-  in this case the System app that implements the lock screen.  Now if you just want to do authentication within your app-  that's doable.  But not on 3rd parties.